# What are the following actions called?

Tags: british-english

If you speak, and another person keeps doing/saying the following at near enough everything you say:

1. Oh here we go again
2. Oh bloody hell
3. Sarcastic laugh
4. Mumbles something to show disapproval but doesn't want to make it too obvious all the time
5. Rolls eyes
6. Tuts

What's that called?  Is there a word which describes what that person is doing?

Comment: They are communicating their skepticism.

Comment: They're carping / cavilling, showing derision, but most people would call them 'obnoxious' or worse.

Comment: I don't know, "British," English: my bad.  Maybe the word is, "interjections."

Answer (score 2):

I would refer to this as scoffing, deriding, or belittling.

Comment: +1 for belittling, especially for the sarcastic laugh, tutting and eye rolling. These behaviors are meant to make you or your input seem trivial, childish and unworthy of a thoughtful response. It's how you might respond to an annoying child who doesn't have the mental capacity to understand a more thorough response.

Comment: You ask me, belittling hits the bull's-eye quite accurately.It's a pretty popular weapon among those unable to find a better way to push themselves upwards, then again it proves double-edged more often than they like to think.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of where you stand on the "pecking order" relative to your critic and regardless of how justified your critic's behavior might seem to be, your critic is **disrespecting** you, being **disrespectful**, and showing **disrespect** by his/her actions.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that they are **mocking you**, **disrespecting you**, or **not taking you seriously**.

Answer (score 0):

A word which might describe this persistent conduct is 'bullying', as it is designed to make the recipient feel less worthy.